# How to check for overfitting with SVM and Iris Data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, overfitting

I am using machine learning predictions for the sample iris dataset. For instance, I am using the support vector machines (SVMs) from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) in order to predict the accuracy. However, it returns an accuracy of 1.0. Here is the code I am using:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=51)
svm_model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma='auto')
svm_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = svm_model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(predictions, y_test)
```

How to find out or to measure if this over-fitting or if the model is so good? I assume that its not over-fitting but what are the best ways to validate this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You check for hints of **overfitting** by using a **training set** and a **test set** (or a training, validation and test set). As others have mentioned, you can either **split** the data into training and test sets, or use **cross-fold validation** to get a more accurate assessment of your classifier's performance.

Since your dataset is small, splitting your data into training and test sets isn't recommended. Use cross validation.

This can be done using either the **cross_validate** or **cross_val_score** function; the latter providing *multiple* metrics for evaluation. In addition to **test scores** the latter also provides **fit times** and **score times**.

Using your example;

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :5]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=51)
svm_model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma='auto')
svm_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = svm_model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(predictions, y_test)
```

raw accuracy: 0.96666666666666667

Using the **cross_val_score** function, and printing the **mean score** and **95% confidence interval** of the score estimate:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

scores = cross_val_score(svm_model, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

Accuracy: 0.98 (+/- 0.03)

Of course the iris dataset is a *toy example*. On larger real-world datasets you are likely to see your test error be higher than your training error, with cross-validation providing a lower accuracy than the raw number.

So I wouldn't use the iris dataset to showcase overfitting. Choose a larger, messier dataset, and then you can start working towards reducing the *bias* and *variance* of the model (the "causes" of overfitting).

Then you can start *exploring* tell-tale **signs** of whether it's a bias problem or a variance problem. See here:

https://www.quora.com/How-many-training-samples-are-needed-to-get-a-reliable-model-in-ML/answer/Sean-McClure-3?srid=zGgv

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem of over-fitting, or that by just doing a single train / test split isn't giving a reliable estimate of the generalizable error of your SVM.

I'd recommend using [KFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) validation to check.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np
acc_score = []

kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):

    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    svm_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    predictions = svm_model.predict(X_test)
    acc_score.append(accuracy_score(predictions, y_test))

np.mean(acc_score)
```

If the average is still 1.0 then you've done good, but my gut feeling is that your high score is dependent on the cut of the data you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(*arrays, **options)` in order to split your data into train and test. Train your model on train-split and use the `predict` method to see the performance on the test data. As an example take a look at the following code which splits the data to two separate groups.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
X

array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])

list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
...
X_train
array([[4, 5],
   [0, 1],
   [6, 7]])
y_train
[2, 0, 3]
X_test
array([[2, 3],
   [8, 9]])
y_test
[1, 4]

train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
```